# Get the package name of any android app on device when it gets opened by user

Tags: android, service, package

I want to get package name of the app when it gets opened. I want to achieve like applock app whenever any app gets open which is locked by applock want to show the lock screen.

I tried some solutions but got no luck.
I am calling below in Service but not getting package name

```
class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {
        final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();
        return isAppOnForeground(context);
    }

    private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
        if (appProcesses == null) {
            return false;
        }
        final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {

                Log.e(TAG, "Process Name : " + appProcess.processName);

                return true;

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the package of the current class by calling `this.getClass().getPackage()`.

The docs for the method are here in the Class docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: I want to get package name of any app opened by user.

Comment: Sorry I think I misread your question, what are you getting when you are calling "final String packageName = context.getPackageName();" ?